# Everything that I need to learn to make mobile apps?

Tags: mobile

So, I never make any mobile apps before, mostly I just make websites. What tools that I need to create let say, an simple reminder app? Like the framework and the database. I searched on Google that Ionic is the most popular framework to develop mobile apps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are a web developer (and don't know React), Ionic may be the easiest option to make a mobile app, although it will not really be a native app. Ionic apps are hybrid, not native. Ionic wraps a website into a mobile app, so it looks like an app and feels like an app, but it's a website. It may have some limitations and performance issues if the app is heavy.

If you know (or want to learn) React, I think [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) is the best option. It's easy to learn once you know React. It's very similar to developing a React web application but it will compile to a native app.

Where I work we are a very small team and we have developed a great app for iOS and Android in a couple months using React Native. None of us have developed a mobile application before.

Beyond that, I think you are a bit confused, you don't need a database to do what you want. You could use the device storage. And if you want to persist the data in a remote database, you could use whichever you want. That has nothing to do with the tools or technologies you use to develop your application.

**Update**: You may want to check out [Expo](https://expo.io/) too, which uses React Native. It seems to be beginner friendly and easy to start with. I've never used it so I can't tell you if it's good, but I have listened good things about Expo.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Matteo! I will do some research about React then.

Comment: @davidchandra You are welcome. I updated my answer adding Expo. Check it out.

Comment: Or just in case, can I use Xamarin? I've been working with c# when making websites though

Comment: Yes, they are different things, though they use the same core and are very similar, but with different targets (web apps and mobile apps).
I don't really know much about Xamarin, but of course you can use it! Use whatever makes you feel more comfortable.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!